# How to configure Reverse proxy for nodejs project and virtualhost for wordpress project

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu-14.04, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

My Objectives:

I want to run the main website like http://dev.abc.com  which is a nodejs project I ran the app.js through pm2 and configured the reverse proxy in virtual host in apache which is perfectly working fine.

Here is the code

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName dev.abc.com

```
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

My second object

There is another project in wordpress which path is /var/www/html/blog
I want to open that blog which is in wordpress setup like http://dev.abc.com/blog

I wrote the code like below

<VirtualHost *:80>

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog

<Directory /var/www/html/blog>

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    AllowOverride All

    Order allow,deny

    allow from all

    Require all granted

</Directory>
```

But did not work. whenever I try to hit it http://dev.abc.com/blog it shows 404 not found page.

How to achieve that thing?

Note:
OS Ubuntu 14.05
webserver apache2
nodejs for main website
wordpress for /blog
php 5.6

Comment: try placing a simple html or php_info() file there under the blog directory and check if everthing is right with apache settings, and if the html is displayed under the same when accessed under your domain_name/blog.

Comment: nothing were work.only 404 showing